# PrimeNG Load only Required Components

Tags: angular, primeng

I added two PrimeNg components to my web site. However I noticed (in Chrome Dev Tools -> Network) that a lot of other components are loading when the first page is being opened. It makes loading of the first page pretty slow.

Is there a way to instruct prime ng to only load a few components?

Comment: I noticed PrimeNG components are built to be pretty modular and reuse components when creating the larger ones. You think it could be pulling down those dependencies? Or is it pulling down stuff you never even touch/need?

Comment: Measuring performance in development doesn't tell much. Create a deployable first where everything is inlined, enable `prodMode`, then measure. In development Angular2 loads hundreds of files that will be reduced to a few in a build step.

Answer (score 6):

Even though it's not documented in their website, it is indeed possible to just load exactly what you need. Just do this:

```
import { Dropdown } from 'primeng/components/dropdown/dropdown';
import { SelectItem } from 'primeng/components/api/selectitem';
```

Source: https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/showcase/setup.component.html

Comment: As of the PrimeNG 5.2.0, you can now simply `import { Calendar } from 'primeng/calendar'` and only get the single component. Some shared interface modules are found in the `primeng/components/common/` folder.